# How to pass a changing number into another class so that it does a command each time that variable changes?

Tags: java, android

I have implemented a class with a `StepCounter` sensor and a variable that grows with 20 for every step. Therefore I want to draw a line/path from a certain point, a few milimeters away from the starting point, for each step. So for 20 steps, the line is further than it would be for 10 steps.

I have created a class thats implements a `CanvasView` and have tried to pass the variable from my `SensorClass` to it, but it won`t draw the line further for each step, it will draw it just once for the main initialisation for variable dir(0).

`MainActivity` class

```
if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)

      if (running) {

            tv_steps.setText(String.valueOf(stepct++));
            dir = dir + 20;

            }



public float getDir(){
    return dir;
}
```

Here is the other class that is supposed to draw the line each time it detects a step

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);     

    Path mPath = new Path();
    mPath.moveTo(startX, startY);

    mPath.lineTo(startX, 1700 - mainActivity.getDir());
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);    

}
```

How should it repeat everytime dir changes? Should i try `drawLine`? Does anybody have another complete different solution then using another class?

Comment: Why not try to start drawing from 0 on y and add increased positive numbers. `starty=0, lineto(startx, starty+getDir()`. Seem improper to have a hard-coded value there as 1700. Better something like `canvas.getHeight()`

Comment: @AndreiVasiu I'm just curious where are you initializing the value of **mPaint**? Maybe its null.